# Выборка MySQL с подзапросом значений из массива

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Есть массив:

```
 $array = [
     '0' => 'Красный',
     '1' => 'Синий',
     '2' => 'Зеленый',
 ];
```

Соответственно `$array[0]` это имеет значение `"Красный"`

Есть SQL запрос:

```
SELECT id, number, color FROM users WHERE status=1
```

В Yii2 выглядит так:

```
$query = User::find()
            ->select(['id','number', 'color'])
            ->where(['status'=>1]);
```

В таблице `users` колонка `color` имеет циферные значения (0,1,2 или 3 и т.д.).
Каким образом мне подставить автоматически значения, чтобы color выводил не 0 а "красный"?
т.е. чтобы было нечто подобное:

```
 SELECT id, number, $array[`color`] AS color_2 FROM users WHERE status=1
```

Пробовал нечто подобное:

```
SELECT id, number, CASE color 
      WHEN 0 THEN 'Красный'
      WHEN 1 THEN 'Синий'
      WHEN 2 THEN 'Зеленый'
      ELSE 'Unknown'
FROM users;
```

Но если массив большой, то CASE вручную прописывать слишком затратно, т.к. начальный массив может дополняться.

Comment: что-то мне кажется что вы задачу представления хотите решать в слое БД или бизнес-логики. решите это с помощью локализаций, например, напрямую, или через виртуальные свойства модели

Comment: @teran т.к. в итоге $query это объект, который потом разбирается во view и строится таблицей, хотелось упростить жизнь, чтобы в объект попадали сразу нужные данные, без редактирования многих view (потому как редактировать/изменять для добавления новых таблиц БД нельзя).

Comment: а просто перекрыть в модели `getColor` какой нибудь нельзя? или еще какой-нить метод маппинга строки таблицы в сущность

Answer (score 1):

Преобразуйте колонку в тип ENUM - будут возвращаться текстовые значения, соответствующие кодам. При этом числовые будут обрабатываться правильно. Для получения чисел - прибавляйте ноль.

> ```
> create table test (id INT, color INT);
> INSERT INTO test select 1,1 union select 2,2;
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | color
> -: | ----:
>  1 |     1
>  2 |     2
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE test CHANGE COLUMN color color ENUM('red', 'green', 'blue');
> select id, color, color + 0 color_code FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | color | color_code
> -: | :---- | ---------:
>  1 | red   |          1
>  2 | green |          2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a391fcf03c3c8fe98a328ce7b2b2640a)*

Comment: Этого нельзя делать. Данные в БД должны оставаться такими как и были, без изменения структуры. Нужно сделать выборку, также как делается подзапросом, но используя в подзапросе не sql а array(ну или json). К тому же, сам массив может в будущем дополняться (и придется каждый раз изменять таблицу, что в принципе невозможно)

Comment: @Jekson353 Ну тогда напишите что-нить типа `SELECT FIELD(color+1, 'Красный', 'Синий', 'Зелёный')`...

Answer (score 0):

Создать вторую таблицу

colors  (id, name)

```
0, Красный
1, Синий
2, Зеленый
```

в запросе LEFT JOIN сделать

```
SELECT 
    users.id, users.number, IF(colors.name iS NULL,"Unknown", colors.name) AS color_2
FROM 
    users
LEFT JOIN 
    colors
ON 
    users.color = colors.id
WHERE 
    users.status=1
```

Comment: Со второй таблицей, все отлично будет работать. Но вот именно, что вопрос с массивом, а не со второй таблицей.

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь класс для хранения ассоциации номера с текстовым названием цвета и метод для получения названия по номеру.

```
class ColorHelper
{
    public const COLOR_DEFAULT = 0;
    public const COLOR_RED = 1;
    public const COLOR_GREEN = 2;
    
    public const COLOR_MAP = [
        self::COLOR_DEFAULT => 'yellow',
        self::COLOR_RED => 'red',
        self::COLOR_GREEN => 'green',
    ];

    /**
     * @param int $color
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getColor(int $color): string
    {
        return self::COLOR_MAP[$color] ?? self::COLOR_MAP[self::COLOR_DEFAULT];
    }
}
```

В классе модели добавляешь метод, который будет возвращать текстовое название цвета

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getColorAsText(): string
{
    return ColorHelper::getColor($this->color);
}
```

В клиентском коде получаешь название цвета.

```
$model->getColorAsText();
```